# Using an internet location with XML Parser

Tags: android, xml, parsing, url

I have a XML file which I use to populate a ListView in my app.
In the beginning, I used a temporary website in order to stash my file; http://www.tempsend.com/7CC3EEA1CA/6335/test6.xml , but as the string keeps changing I cannot use this in my app as I will need to update the file every day.

Hence, I have access to a server at which I have placed the XML file; http://www.smashing72.nl/test6.xml

The app works perfectly fine with the first URL, but it closes the application on start-up with the second one, how is this possible?!

More important, how can I fix this?

```
public class Zoeken extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    ListView listview;
    LVA adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    EditText editsearch;
    static String ARTNR = "ArtNr";
    static String ARTOM = "ArtOm";
    static String OPSLAGLOC = "OpslagLoc";
    static String AANTAL = "Aantal";
    private List<Test4> test4List = null;

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadXML AsyncTask
        new DownloadXML().execute();
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.zoeken, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // action with ID action_refresh was selected
            case R.id.refresh:
                new DownloadXML().execute();
                break;
                default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewartnr);
        //pass results to
        adapter = new LVA(Zoeken.this,
                test4List);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
        editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchartnr);

        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    }



    // DownloadXML AsyncTask
    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Zoeken.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Lexro Artikelnummers Zoeken");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Laden...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            test4List = new ArrayList<Test4>();
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            // Retrive nodes from the given website URL in XMLParser.class
            String xml = parser
                    .getXmlFromUrl("http://www.tempsend.com/7CC3EEA1CA/6335/test6.xml");
            // Retrive DOM element
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

            try {
                // Locate the NodeList name
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    Test4 map = new Test4();
                    map.setArtNr(parser.getValue(e, ARTNR));
                    map.setArtOm(parser.getValue(e, ARTOM));
                    map.setOpslagLoc(parser.getValue(e, OPSLAGLOC));
                    map.setAantal(parser.getValue(e, AANTAL));

                    test4List.add(map);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewartnr);
            //pass results to
            adapter = new LVA(Zoeken.this,
                    test4List);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
            editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchartnr);

            // Capture Text in EditText
            editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
                            .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    adapter.filter(text);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                              int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }


    }

    // DownloadXML AsyncTask
    private class recall extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewartnr);
            //pass results to
            adapter = new LVA(Zoeken.this,
                    test4List);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
            editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchartnr);

            // Capture Text in EditText
            editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
                            .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    adapter.filter(text);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                              int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }


    }



}
```

LVA Class:

```
 public class LVA extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> overzicht;
    private List<Test4> test4List = null;
    private ArrayList<Test4> arraylist;

    public LVA(Context context,
               List<Test4> test4List) {
        this.context = context;
        this.test4List = test4List;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Test4>();
        for (Test4 item : test4List) {
            if (item != null) {
                arraylist.add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView ArtNr;
        TextView ArtOm;
        TextView OpslagLoc;
        TextView Aantal;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return test4List.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return test4List.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.ArtNr = (TextView) view.findViewById(ArtNr);
            holder.ArtOm = (TextView) view.findViewById(ArtOm);
            holder.OpslagLoc = (TextView) view.findViewById(OpslagLoc);
            holder.Aantal = (TextView) view.findViewById(Aantal);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.ArtNr.setText(test4List.get(position).getArtNr());
        holder.ArtOm.setText(test4List.get(position).getArtOm());
        holder.OpslagLoc.setText(test4List.get(position).getOpslagLoc());
        holder.Aantal.setText(test4List.get(position).getAantal());


        // Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("ArtNr",
                        (test4List.get(position).getArtNr()));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("ArtOm",
                        (test4List.get(position).getArtOm()));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("OpslagLoc",
                        (test4List.get(position).getOpslagLoc()));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("Aantal",
                        (test4List.get(position).getAantal()));
                // Pass all data population
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class ; Kijk naar getArtNr voor aanpassen zoekvariabele
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        test4List.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            for (Test4 item : test4List) {
                if (item != null) {
                    arraylist.add(item);
                } else {
                    for (Test4 wp : arraylist) {
                        if (wp.getArtNr().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                                .contains(charText)) {
                            test4List.add(wp);
                        }
                        if (wp.getArtOm().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                                .contains(charText)) {
                            test4List.add(wp);
                        }
                        if (wp.getOpslagLoc().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                                .contains(charText)) {
                            test4List.add(wp);
                        }
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-11 10:37:04.371  18219-18251/com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse E/DataScheduler﹕ isDataSchedulerEnabled():false
04-11 10:37:04.641  18219-18251/com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse E/Error:﹕ expected: /META read: HEAD (position:END_TAG </HEAD>@11:8 in java.io.StringReader@42965218)
04-11 10:37:04.641  18219-18251/com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41818e48)
04-11 10:37:04.641  18219-18251/com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse, PID: 18219
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
            at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
            at com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse.Zoeken$DownloadXML.doInBackground(Zoeken.java:194)
            at com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse.Zoeken$DownloadXML.doInBackground(Zoeken.java:154)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-11 10:37:05.551  18219-18219/com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse.Zoeken has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{428ba790 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,486} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:377)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:296)
            at com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse.Zoeken$DownloadXML.onPreExecute(Zoeken.java:166)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse.Zoeken.onCreate(Zoeken.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat output, otherwise it will be difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Ok so reviewing this I can tell the one where the error occurs it throws a NullPointerException. But why does it do this whilst it is exactly the same file, yet stored in another location?!

Answer (score 0):

The logcat tells you pretty much exactly what's wrong. The interesting part is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
            at com.androidbegin.searchxmlparse.XMLParser.LVA.<init>(LVA.java:38)
```

There is a `NullPointerException` when you try to add object to an ArrayList. So the problem can only be:

1. You list is null. That is unlikely since it works with the other rss feed.
2. The Rss Feed is not parsed correctly and there are some objects in your list or some fields of those objects which are null.

You should put a breakpoint into the Constructor of your LVA class (I think it's your Adapter) and debug exactly what is going on. The line where you call `addAll(...)` is where the problem occurs. I cannot help you further since you have not posted the code of the LVA class.

**EDIT:**

Try replacing the line `this.arraylist.addAll(test4List);` in the constructor of your LVA class with this:

```
for(Test4 item : test4List) {
    if(item != null) {
        arrayList.add(item);
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, add a breakpoint to the constructor of the LVA class and debug it until you find out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I'm starting to get it now, the thing I find weird is that it does work on the one feed, but not on the other, so it has to do something with the location the XML file is stored at?! I cannot find any information on how to store your XML file for parsing.

Anyways, I added the LVA class to the original post, which indeed is my ListViewAdapter. Thanks for helping me out!!

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the constructor and debug it. Look at all the values the variables have. Most likely some element in the list `test4List` is null. Personally I have one rule: Never trust `addAll()`. I had a lot of problems with `addAll()` in the past because it just doesn't work right sometimes. I will edit my answer with suggestions.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the addAll() to your code, and now it gives another error in the logcat, I have no clue what it means.

Thanks for helping me!!

Comment: The logcat tells you again pretty much exactly what's wrong, my first suggestion would be to change this line in your DownloadXML AsyncTask: `Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());` to this: `Log.e("Error", e);`.

Comment: I really appriciate you helping me, but when I try to change it to the suggested line it gives an immidiate error saying "e string in log cannot be applied to string java.lang.exeption". I'm lost...

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant replace it with this: `Log.e("Error", "Some Message" , e);`

Comment: It still isn't working, but it must have to do something with the XML file, anyways, you helped me great! Thanks a heap! Unfortunately I do not have enough rep to upvote!